# Mail Content for Codeigniter always Wrapped

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, sendmail

I don't know which part wrong with my code, i am going to sendmail as HTML in codeigniter, but my mail always get wrapped in 76 character, although i've been set word wrap to false.

Here is my code :

```
 $content    = "<html>";
    $content    .= "Dear GA,<br/><br/>";
    $content    .= "You have request for Car use, below is the detail data :<br/>";
    $content    .= "<b>Request No :</b> ".$reqno."<br/>";
    $content    .= "<b>Date :</b> ".$date."<br/>";
    $content    .= "<b>Time :</b> ".$time."<br/>";
    $content    .= "<b>Destination :</b> ".$dest."<br />";
    $content    .= "<b>Passenger :</b> (".$jml.") ".$pasr."<br />";
    $content    .= "<br /><br /><br /><i style='color:grey'>Send By WIS System Automatic Mail</i></html>";

    $ci = get_instance();
    $ci->load->library('email');
    $ci->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $ci->email->set_wordwrap(FALSE);
    $ci->email->from('noreply@chingluh.co.id', 'WIS System');

    $ci->email->to('mymail@mycompany.co.id');
    $ci->email->subject('Car Request');
    $ci->email->message($content);

    if ($this->email->send()) {

        echo 'Email sent.';
    }
    else{

        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

but the html source result always like this (wrapped with equal sign)

```
<html>Dear GA,<br/><br/>You have request for Car use, below is the detail d=
ata :<br/><b>Request No :</b> C15L020<br/><b>Date :</b> 2015-12-11<br/><b>T=

ime :</b> 10:00<br/><b>Destination :</b> Jakarta<br /><b>Passenger :</b> (2=
) Passenger name<br /><br /><br /><br /><i style=3D'color:grey'>Send By WIS =
System Automatic Mail</i></html>
```

could anyone give me an advice, what should i do ?

thanks before

Answer (score 0):

Please include this code i am not sure but try it

```
  $ci->email->subject('Car Request');
$ci->$email->IsHTML(true);
```

Comment: hi Digpal, thanks for your response. But, i get this error after apply your code : `Call to undefined method CI_Email::IsHTML()`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['charset']      = 'utf-8';
$config['mailtype']     = 'html';
$config['wordwrap'] = FALSE;



//your SMTP settings
$config['protocol']     = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']    = 'exchange.example.com'; //ssl://
$config['smtp_user']    = 'email@example.com';
$config['smtp_pass']    = 'password';
$config['smtp_port']    = 25;

$this->email->set_newline( "\r\n" );
$this->email->set_crlf( "\r\n" );

$this->email->initialize( $config );

$this->email->clear();

// 
$content    = "<html>";
$content    .= "Dear GA,<br/><br/>";
$content    .= "You have request for Car use, below is the detail data :<br/>";
$content    .= "<b>Request No :</b> ".$reqno."<br/>";
$content    .= "<b>Date :</b> ".$date."<br/>";
$content    .= "<b>Time :</b> ".$time."<br/>";
$content    .= "<b>Destination :</b> ".$dest."<br />";
$content    .= "<b>Passenger :</b> (".$jml.") ".$pasr."<br />";
$content    .= "<br /><br /><br /><i style='color:grey'>Send By WIS System Automatic Mail</i></html>";


$this->email->from( $frome, $fromn );
$this->email->to( $email );

$this->email->subject( $subject );


$this->email->message( $content);


$this->email->send();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reponse Dray, but nothing difference after i try your code.

Comment: in my case, yes it still

Answer (score 0):

These is an old post but could help others.
I cannot see your configuration but let me tell you that I had the same problem by months and I had not fix it until now.
Let me show my configuration, maybe could help you too. 
good luck!

```
/*--- Mail Init Config ---*/
    $config                 = array();
    $config['useragent']    = 'My company';
    $config['protocol']     = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host']    = 'smtp.office365.com';
    $config['smtp_user']    = 'someemail@outlook.com';
    $config['smtp_pass']    = 'myPassword';
    $config['smtp_port']    = 587;
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = 30;
    $config['smtp_crypto']  = 'tls';
    $config['wrapchars']    = 76;
    $config['mailtype']     = 'html';
    $config['charset']      = 'utf-8';
    $config['wordwrap']     = TRUE;
    $config['crlf']         = "\r\n";  //in my case new line added
    $config['newline']      = "\r\n";
    $config['bcc_batch_mode'] = FALSE;
    $config['bcc_batch_size'] = 200;
    $config['dsn']          = FALSE;
```